# MVC ActionLink triggers a RouteConstraint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this simple User `Area` in my `MVC 4` project.

```
public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName { get { return "User"; } }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute("User_Constraint",
                "{userName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { userName = string.Empty, controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { userName = new UserNameRouteConstraint() },
                new[] { "T2b.Web.Areas.User.Controllers" }
            );
    }
}
```

To make sure the User Name exists I have a `RouteConstraint` called `UserNameRouteConstraint()`

All this does is a simple lookup in my users table and return true if the user has been found.

So far so good, this construction works fine!

Now; My view in the User `Area` has the following line of code

```
@Html.ActionLink("More information", "details", new {id = product.Guid})
```

This single line causes the `UserNameRouteConstraint()` to be called....

How and why!? If I write the link in plain `HTML` (see example below) it works well, but I want to keep to the `MVC` Principles as close as possible.

```
<a href="/username/Products/details/@product.Guid">More information</a>
```

Is there any way to prevent the `RouteConstraint` call?

Comment: how your plain html (<a href.../>) looks like?

Comment: I've added the `HTML` line... Just simple `HTML` :-)

Comment: you are passing "username" for {userName}. it will require a user with  name "username" to be exist. is it provided?

Comment: No, that is not the case. The `RouteConstraint` is not called when using plain `HTML` (in my test case I used a real user name) and the `RouteConstraint` IS called when using `ActionLink`...

Comment: So the RouteConstraint is being used as a sort of Authorization system? Why not use the providers or is this in conjunction with the aforementioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever routes are generated the constraints are processed.

You can add this check to stop the constraint depending on whether the constraint is handling an incoming request or generating a URL from a function like `ActionLink`:

```
public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if(routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)
        return false;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ActionLink` behind the scenes it creates a `RouteValueDictionary` and runs `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath()`.  This part is not open source but my best guess as to how it works is that it checks the parameters of the generated route value dictionary against the defaults and constraints of each route until it finds one that matches.  Because of this it runs your constraints, and you should want it to run your constraints so that it doesn't end up matching to the wrong route.